# Specify Request/Response Modals in Nodejs + express APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, request

I've created an API in nodejs + express => update user API where data comes in body

```
router.patch('/profile', verifyAuth, updateProfile);
```

In updateProfile  using `const reqData = req.body` I'm updating the reqData in user modal

data such as:

```
{
 firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  gender: string,
  dateOfBirth: Date,
  email: string,
  phone: string,
}
```

Here phone number is my unique key so, I don't want anyone to update phone and there are many other keys as well.

Therefore I want to capture only fields which I want to update in req.body for update profile API.

Is there a way to specify request modal for APIs in express nodejs? If someone add any other keys in request it will be neglected in req.body

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you :)
To skip the update of th phone number, you just have to skip the key "phone" in the dictionnary.

Have a nice day.

```js
function checkProfile(item){
    return {
    firstName: item.firstName,
    lastName: item.lastName,
    gender: item.gender,
    dateOfBirth: item.dateOfBirth,
    email: item.email,
    phone: item.phone,
  }
}

const rawProfile = {
    firstName: "string",
  lastName: "string",
  gender: "string",
  dateOfBirth: new Date(),
  email: "string",
  phone: "string",
  additionalValue1:"xxxxxx",
  additionalValue2:"xxxxxx",
  additionalValue3:"xxxxxx",
}

console.log(checkProfile(rawProfile))
```

Comment: Hi @Dieunelson I've to skip lots of keys. and very few keys I have to update. Also, there are lots of update queries so, I can't create object to skip keys.